# Using PHP to change file encoding generates newlines

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, iconv

I use PHP to change file encoding, but it generates a new empty line after each line.

```
$t_comment = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
$t_comment = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE",$t_comment);
echo $t_comment;
```

Here is *myfile.txt*:

> line1 **[CR][LF]**
>   line2 **[CR][LF]**
>   line3 **[CR][LF]**

Conversion command (BATCH):

```
C:\> type myfile.txt | php.exe myscript.php
```

or

```
C:\> php.exe myscript.php < myfile.txt
```

Result:

> line1 **[LF]**
>   **[LF]**
>   line2 **[LF]**
>   **[LF]**
>   line3 **[LF]**
>   **[LF]**

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: can you provide a hexdump of your input?

Comment: show how you call your script / how you provide STDIN from the outside of this script .... `cat myfile.txt | php myscript.php`? did you try `php myscript.php < myfile.txt`? which shell are you using?

Comment: @Kaii I have to use a windows BATCH file, I tried both syntax, it doesn't change anything. It really seems that `iconv` has a strange behaviour...

Answer (score 3):

You have alternative functions: [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8-encode) and [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb-convert-encoding), although I have tested `iconv` locally and it works, but I am not using Windows.

Considering you are on Windows and using `type` to generate the PHP script input, you should check the active console code page, which may be affecting the output of the `type` command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true

First, try to discard the problem being with `iconv` by changing the first line of your code to the following, and seeing what happens:

```
$t_comment = "line 1 \r\nline 2 \r\nline 3 \r\n";
```

Comment: Ok, I have completely changed the answer.

Comment: The console code page 850 by default, I tried to change it to 863 but it didn't changed anything. The problem doesn't seem to come from `iconv` since `echo`ing the input file without changes causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the new lines were generated because of the double pipe command. So I decided to merge both sripts to have only one pipe.

So I changed:

```
C:\> type myfile.txt | php.exe myscript1.php | php.exe myscript2.php
```

to:

```
C:\> type myfile.txt | php.exe myscript1-merge2.php
```

This fixes the problem but doesn't answer where do the extra newlines came from.